# files.length is undefined in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using

```
$(upload_button).bind('change', function(event) 
{
    var files = this.files;
    alert(typeof(files));
    if(typeof(files)!='undefined')
    {


    }
});
```

in my code with jQuery which is working fine in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE8(i.e., IE returns undefined for **files.length**, whereas others returns the value). So do anybody know how to resolve this?

Comment: I suspect that `input` is not a good choice as variable identifier in IE... :) but maybe it's just me and I'm getting too old and suspicious

Comment: Which version of IE? IE6/7/8? `files` property doesn't work or `this`?

Comment: Okay, what's the rest of the code (up to, and including, the `});` closing the `bind()` method)? And what part isn't working?

Comment: why do you create `var file;`? You don't end the function correctly. How is `upload_button` referenced?

Comment: Could you give more details on which par do you have problem?

Comment: what is upload_button? what line raises the error? what the error raised?

Comment: may be dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480934/pass-filename-from-file-upload-to-text-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because Internet Explorer, even IE9 [does not support HTML5 File API](http://caniuse.com/fileapi) and therefore it returns `undefined` value for `files` property.

Comment: So is there any hack available for that?

Comment: @Udhay I don't know, maybe IE10. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772931(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

From [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
 `change` event will not work with button as I am assuming upload_button is button.